# How can I read a smaller ByteBuffer from a larger ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, bytebuffer

Whilst the `ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer)` method is present, `ByteBuffer.get(ByteBuffer)` seems to be missing? How am I supposed to achieve reading a smaller `ByteBuffer` from a larger `ByteBuffer`?

Comment: Which bytes from the buffer do you want to read? What does it mean to read a `ByteBuffer` from a `ByteBuffer`?

Comment: If I were to pass byte[], a standard byte array of set size, to ByteBuffer.get(byte) the array would be filled. I'm looking to emulate this functionality with ByteBuffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists the `ByteBuffer#put` method:

> **public ByteBuffer put(ByteBuffer src)** : This method transfers the bytes remaining in the given source buffer into this buffer

You are looking for something like

> **public ByteBuffer get(ByteBuffer dst)** : This method transfers the bytes remaining in this buffer into the given target buffer

But consider that operations `get` and `put` are somewhat symmetric.

```
ByteBuffer src = ...
ByteBuffer dst = ...
//src.get(dst); // Does not exist
dst.put(src); // Use this instead
```

You explicitly talked about *smaller* and *larger* buffers. So I assume that the `dst` buffer is smaller than the `src` buffer. In this case, you can simply set the limit of the source buffer accordingly:

```
ByteBuffer src = ...
ByteBuffer dst = ...
int oldLimit = src.limit();
src.limit(src.position()+dst.remaining());
dst.put(src);
src.limit(oldLimit);
```

Alternative formulations are possible (e.g. using a `ByteBuffer#slice()` of the original buffer). But in any case, you do **not** have to copy the buffer contents into a new byte array just to transfer it into another buffer!

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading the [API page for ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

`ByteBuffer get(byte[])`

and

`ByteBuffer get(byte[] dst, int offset, int length)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need to re-wrap the `byte[]` in a new `ByteBuffer`.

```
ByteByffer buffer = ...;
byte[] sub = new byte[someSize];
buffer.get(sub [, ..]); // use appropriate get(..) method
buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(sub);
```